# multiply contents of a column with combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, multiplication

I want to multiply the contents of my "price" column in my datagridview by a selected amount in a combo box and display it in the same column "price".

Can you help me? I do not know how to run it.

Comment: A common approach is to read all of the values on your form into an object that represents the domain object (e.g. an order or an invoice), apply your business logic to the object and write the values back to the form. Common approaches to address this kind of issue are the MVC and MVP patterns (you can google them). But without showing us more detail of what you have tried and why it is not working, this question should be closed for being too broad. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12283085)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you can do like this in combox box selected index change event:

```
   private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        double selected = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox1.SelectedItem);
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();        
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);

        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var price = Convert.ToDouble(row["price"]);
            var calculation = //do your calculation here with **price** and **selected** value above from combo box
            row["price"] = calculation.ToString();
        }

        datagridview.Source = table;

    }
```

above select command can be you any select command from database.